# Python Cplex Ceil() Function

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex, ceil, docplex

[ceil() in the constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbJ1E.png)

Hello, I am studying a published paper. One of the constraints from this paper(*which can be shown in the link*) requires the ceil() function. We can use the ceil() function at the OPL but I couldn't find the Python equality.

Notice: I tried the math.ceil() and cp.moduler ceil(), but I did not get any solution.

Edit:
I still haven't found its Python equivalent, but there is an alternative way:

```
slack_var = model.continuous_var(name="slack")

ceiled_var = model.integer_var(name='ceiled')
```

> Notice: The slack variable has to be less than "1". ( 0 <= slack < 1)

```
ceiled_var - slack_var = "your calculations"
```

Comment: Maybe the resulting model is infeasible.

Comment: I got the solution in OPL. The model is okay, but I couldn't code in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For ceil, you can use both math or numpy, however, numpy can be overkill.

```
import math
ceiled_variable = math.ceil(your_variable)
```

or

```
import numpy as np
ceiled_variable = np.ceil(your_variable)
```

Comment: No, You need to use Cplex's ceil as the expression contains decision variables.

Comment: As Erwin said, We have to use the Cplex's Ceil(). But, I couldn't find the Python equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

ceil is not a linear function so you should linearize. See example [here](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithdocplex/blob/main/ceil.py).

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='ceil')

r=range(0,4)
x=[1.5,4.0,2.0001,5.9999]

y = mdl.integer_var_list(4,0,1000,name="y")
f = mdl.continuous_var_list(4,0,0.9999999,name="f")

for i in r:
    mdl.add(y[i]==x[i]+f[i])

mdl.solve()

for i in r:
    print(x[i]," ==> ",y[i].solution_value)

"""
which gives
1.5  ==>  2.0
4.0  ==>  4.0
2.0001  ==>  3.0
5.9999  ==>  6.0
"""
```

Comment: Yes, It looks like my alternative way. I would like to ask you something. We can use ceil() function for the linear models in the OPL without linearization. How is it possible?  Does OPL's ceil() function make linearization?

Comment: Same in opl : https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/ceil.mod